# cannot add password to user name with hyphen (-) in Terminal Code

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu

I created a Data Base with user smart-brain. And i wanted to add a password to it. which always gives me error

I tried creating another user without the hyphen and there was no problem. 
Using Linux ubuntu 
https://gyazo.com/03a58dcbd539a75868d886d66ca299a9

```
createdb 'smart-brain'
psql 'smart-brain'
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.
smart-brain=# ALTER USER smart-brain WITH PASSWORD 'test123';
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
LINE 1: ALTER USER smart-brain WITH PASSWORD 'test123';
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but valid Postgres identifiers can only include letters, digits, underscore, or dollar sign.  Hyphen does not appear to be included in that list.  This means that, assuming user `smart-brain` even exists, you should be escaping it using double quotes.  Try the following alter statement:

```
ALTER USER "smart-brain" WITH PASSWORD 'test123';
```